# What volume serial number is returned by GetFileInformationByHandleEx?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, ntfs

I am using [GetFileInformationByHandleEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get [FILE_ID_INFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802691(v=vs.85).aspx) it contains VolumeSerialNumber field. For some file located on my logical volume C: it is 32B7232F at the same time vol C: shows that Volume Serial Number is 14B8-B987. The same returns WMI requests for Win32_Volume and Win32_LogicalDisk. Why volume s/n differs?

---

Some Code:

```
//
// Internal file system file id. This FILE_ID_INFORMATION is defined in ntifs.h for kernel mode and the same structure with name
// FILE_ID_INFO in winnt.h for user mode, so we should implement our own. FILE_ID_128 is common in winnt.h  and ntifs.h.
//
typedef struct _MYFILE_ID_INFORMATION {
    ULONGLONG VolumeSerialNumber; // Protected file volume serial number
    FILE_ID_128 FileId;           // File id on volume
} MYFILE_ID_INFORMATION, *PMYFILE_ID_INFORMATION;

_Must_inspect_result_
HRESULT
WINAPI
GetFileId(
_In_ LPCWSTR filePath,
_Out_ PMYFILE_ID_INFORMATION info
)
/*++

Routine Description:

    Retrieves internal file system file id for a given file.

Arguments:

    filePath - The path and name of the file to create.

    info - pointer to a caller-allocated variable that receives the address of internal file system file id structure.

Return Value:

    The final status of this operation.

--*/
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    HRESULT result = S_OK;

    hFile = CreateFileW(filePath,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        (DWORD)NULL,
        (HANDLE)NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    __try
    {
        BOOL retVal = GetFileInformationByHandleEx(hFile, FileIdInfo, (LPVOID)info, sizeof(MYFILE_ID_INFORMATION));
        if (!retVal) {
            result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: *For some file located on my logical volume C:* Please don't make us guess. Show exactly how you got the file handle that you passed to `GFIBHE`.

Comment: I've just realised that I cannot help you since I don't have a Win8 machine to hand. Sorry.

Comment: What is it PAAFILE_ID_INFORMATION ?

Comment: @Xearinox It only makes sense if that is, `PMYFILE_ID_INFORMATION`. It's a shame that the real code wasn't posted......

Comment: The docs say `FileIdInfo` is only supported on Server 2012, not Windows 8. Are you sure the function is actually succeeding and you're not just seeing uninitialised memory?

Comment: @Xearinox,   David Heffernan  PAAFILE_ID_INFORMATION  = PMYFILE_ID_INFORMATION..sory. I corrected the code. Are you sure the function is actually succeeding and you're not just seeing uninitialised memory? Yes absolutly. This id is the same in kernel.

Comment: I *think* this is a different serial number, meaningful only to the kernel and/or file system driver.

Comment: If you're trying to identify a volume by VSN, the obvious workaround would be to enumerate all the volumes on the system, then open the root directory for each and use GetFileInformationByHandleEx to get the VSN and compare.

Comment: Also, have you checked whether the VSN returned is the same after rebooting the system?  I don't think the specification necessarily requires it to be.

Comment: @HarryJohnston It is the same across reboots.